# safe copy file python program - what's problem in code

Tags: python, file, copy, shutil

I'm trying to copy the files from one destination to another and i follow this program and i don't know what i did the mistake but files are not copying to destination folder.
https://gist.github.com/alexwlchan/c2adbb8ee782f460e5ec

I don't know about too much about programming i just follow the tutorial.

I added extra in this code

```
src = ("F:\\Work\\")
dst = ("F:\\ws\\")
```

So please correct me if i'm wrong.

Thanks in advance !

```
import filecmp
import os
import shutil

src = ("F:\\Work\\")
dst = ("F:\\ws\\")

def _increment_filename(filename, marker='-'):
    basename, fileext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if marker not in basename:
        base = basename
        value = 0
    else:
        base, counter = basename.rsplit(marker, 1)
        try:
            value = int(counter)
        except ValueError:
            base = basename
            value = 0
    while True:
        if value == 0:
            value += 1
            yield filename
        value += 1
        yield '%s%s%d%s' % (base, marker, value, fileext)

def copyfile(src, dst):
    if not os.path.exists(src):
        raise ValueError('Source file does not exist: {}'.format(src))

    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dst)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dst))

    while True:

        dst_gen = _increment_filename(dst)
        dst = next(dst_gen)

        if os.path.exists(dst):

            if filecmp.cmp(src, dst):
                return dst
            else:

                try:
                    src_fd = os.open(src, os.O_RDONLY)
                    dst_fd = os.open(dst, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_EXCL|os.O_CREAT|os.O_EXLOCK)

                # Read 100 bytes at a time, and copy them from src to dst
                    while True:
                        data = os.read(src_fd, 100)
                        os.write(dst_fd, data)

                    # When there are no more bytes to read from the source
                    # file, 'data' will be an empty string
                        if not data:
                            break

                # If we get to this point, then the write has succeeded
                    return dst

                except OSError as e:
                    if e.errno != 17 or e.strerror != 'File exists':
                        raise
                    else:
                        print('Race condition: %s just popped into existence' % dst)

                finally:
                    os.close(src_fd)
                    os.close(dst_fd)

        # Copying to this destination path has been unsuccessful, so increment
        # the path and try again
            dst = next(dst_gen)

def move(src, dst):
    dst = copyfile(src, dst)
    os.remove(src)
    return dst
```

There is no error in program, program run fine but the destination folder is blank.

**Expected result should be files copy to destination folder & below expected resulted according to program**

If a file already exists at dst, it will not be overwritten, but:

```
 * If it is the same as the source file, do nothing
 * If it is different to the source file, pick a new name for the copy that
   is distinct and unused, then copy the file there.
```

Comment: You will have to call the `move` function somewhere.

Comment: @KlausD. `copyfile` should be called, not `move`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but that code seems to be massively overcomplicated for what it is. this should work in almost all cases. If *dst* already exists, it will add underscores ( _ ) to the directory name until an unused one is found:

```
import os
import shutil
import filecmp

src = ("D:\\Documents\\oof")
dst = ("D:\\oof")
validextensions = ["jpeg", "txt", "pdf", "pptx"]


def copydir(src, dst):
    if not os.path.isdir(src):
        print("Source directory doesn't exist.")
        return None
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.mkdir(dst)
    elif not os.path.isdir(dst):
        while not os.path.isdir(dst):
            dst += "_"
        os.mkdir(dst)

    for file in os.listdir(src):
        frompath = os.path.join(src, file)
        topath = os.path.join(dst, file)
        if os.path.isfile(frompath):
            complete = False
            if not any([file[-1 * len(ext):] == ext for ext in validextensions]):
                complete = True
            while not complete:
                if os.path.isfile(topath):
                    if filecmp.cmp(frompath, topath):
                        complete = True
                    else:
                        topath = topath[:topath.index(".")] + "_" + topath[topath.index("."):]
                else:
                    shutil.copyfile(frompath, topath)
                    complete = True
        elif os.path.isdir(frompath):
            copydir(frompath, topath)


copydir(src, dst)
```

I'm loving how this is progressively becoming more complex as OP lists more features they wanted *facepalm*

Comment: Thanks ! , this program just copy the files from one directory to another but the program which I'm working also create the new file if it already exist at destination so not override the existing file.

Comment: @3ws I could see that in your code, however you hadn't specified that that was what you were trying to do in your brief.

Comment: The code in the question also deals with possible race conditions, which the `shutil` functions don't seem to do, judging by a quick glance over the code. That does not seem to be a requirement of the OP, however. One recommendation though: use `os.path.join` instead of string concatenation when composing file system paths.

Comment: @shmee I was considering that the OP had said they weren't that experienced with code and that they hadn't specified the features they wanted, and thus made the solution as simple as possible. ah, that's the one I was thinking of. Couldn't quite remember the function name!

Comment: just face a problem I can't copy the folder using above program it show the error like--- Traceback <most recent call last>;
 file "program.py", line 17,  in copydir
  shutil.copyfile<frompath,topath>
  file "c:\Users\user\Appdata\Local\Program\......\....\..\..\shutil,py, l;ine 120 , in copyfile
  with open <src,'rb'> as fsrc:
 PermissionErrr: [Errno 13] permission dendied: 'F:\\work\\FolderName

Comment: @3ws Oh, you're trying to copy directories within directories. Again, you should have told us that.

Comment: Thanks again Dear :) your last updated program not work...again some permission error (when there is a folder )

Comment: @3ws OP, the program is now capable of copying nested directories, will not copy duplicate files, but will alter the filenames of files with duplicate filenames that are distinct, and will also create the _dst_ directory if it doesn't exist. Anything else you want to spring on us now?

Comment: My actual goal is --- 

--- first copy the files
--- if there is any change in these file then create the new file with some extra name
---other file not copy again those are not changed 


Your program doing little bit different 

Trying to modified maybe i can acheive my goal.

Comment: @3ws Actually, as I understand it, that's _exactly_ what my code does. On my system it is, anyways. What's it doing wrong? Have you got the most recently updated version?

Comment: Thank you so much...Done ...!!!  in any way we can done some changes only copy the particular Extension files to destination ?

Comment: only copy the particular extension files like (.jpeg,pdf,txt) etc, to destination folder.

Comment: @3ws Done. Add / remove valid extensions from the validextensions list at the top. Are you getting paid for this?

Comment: No..I'm just student completing my college project. If someone paid me for this then definitely  i will post this to Freelancer. Thank you so much for the help dear.

Comment: @3ws Ah. Right.

Comment: Oh, wow ... this ended up being almost as complex as the original code :D Btw: this no longer holds true: `Assuming the dst folder is empty`. +1 for the _faceplam_ ... you should at least get _something_ out of this ordeal. :)

Comment: @shmee Ah, yes, thankyou. _Ordeal_ is for sure the right word. Yeah, maybe I'll actually remember that _os.path_ exists rather than having to _help(os)_ next time.